# Understanding ViennaRNA RNAdistance scoring table

Tags: sequence-alignment, rna, rna-alignment, rna-structure

I'm trying to compare the output of 2 different algorithms of RNA structure prediction
(my implementation of Nussinov vs RNA-mfold algorithm) using the [RNAdistance](https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/RNAdistance.1.html) algorithm that is part of [ViennaRNA](https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/) package.
I'm getting a distance score of 38 between Nussinov prediction and the actual NMR structure, and a score of 14 between the m-fold algorithm and the NMR structure and I'm trying to understand whether it is a big difference.

In order to do that I have to look at the scoring table that is used by RNAdistance and found the following `score table` in the [source code](https://github.com/ViennaRNA/ViennaRNA/blob/ea2e71f98c3a6a98310fa5f25e9626e970f112d9/src/ViennaRNA/edit_cost.h):

```
RIVATE CostMatrix  UsualCost =
{

/*    Null,       U,        P,        H,        B,        I,        M,        S,        E,        R     */

   {        0,        1,        2,        2,        2,        2,        2,        1,        1, DIST_INF},   /* Null replaced */
   {        1,        0,        1, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF},   /* U    replaced */
   {        2,        1,        0, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF},   /* P    replaced */
   {        2, DIST_INF, DIST_INF,        0,        2,        2,        2, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF},   /* H    replaced */
   {        2, DIST_INF, DIST_INF,        2,        0,        1,        2, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF},   /* B    replaced */
   {        2, DIST_INF, DIST_INF,        2,        1,        0,        2, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF},   /* I    replaced */
   {        2, DIST_INF, DIST_INF,        2,        2,        2,        0, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF},   /* M    replaced */
   {        1, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF,        0, DIST_INF, DIST_INF},   /* S    replaced */
   {        1, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF,        0, DIST_INF},   /* E    replaced */
   { DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF, DIST_INF,        0},   /* R    replaced */

};
```

I also found the [enter link description here](https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/ViennaRNA/doc/html/distance_measures.html)following explanation, but **I do not understand what is the meaning of the table letters: U,P,H,B,I,MS,E,R ?**

What is the meaning of the score of [H,B] = 2 for example?
If anyone can explain the table it will be a great help in my project, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the answer was right [here](https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/RNAdistance.1.html) and I missed it, posting it in case anyone else will do the same mistake as me in the future.

```
U = unpaired
P = paired
H = hairpin
B = bulge
I = internal loop
M = multiloop
S = stem (or stack)
E = external loop
```